# Coding Enigma algorithm, can encrypt but not decrypt

Tags: c, cryptography

I have to code the enigma algorithm used by Nazi-Germany to encrypt messages sent over radio, you can read how it works right [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2018sp/a1/a1.html)

As of right now i am only coding the rotors, i didn't code the Plugboard or the rotor initial position yet, since i seem to have problems with this already.

This is what i wrote:

```
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(sentence);i++){

        sentence[i]=toupper(sentence[i]);

        temp=rs1[0];
        for(int s=0;s<26-1;s++)
        {
            rs1[s]=rs1[s+1];
        }
        rs1[26-1]=temp;
        j++;

        if (j==26){

            j=0;
            temp=rs2[0];
            for(int s=0;s<26-1;s++)
            {
                rs2[s]=rs2[s+1];
            }
            rs2[26-1]=temp;
            z++;

        }

        if (z==26){

            z=0;
            temp=rs2[0];
            for(int s=0;s<26-1;s++)
            {
                rs2[s]=rs2[s+1];
            }
            rs2[26-1]=temp;

        }

        q=(sentence[i]-65);

        //this cant decrypt

        sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],rs1);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);
        sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],rs2);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);
        sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],rs3);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);
        sentence[i]=reflect(sentence[i]);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);
        sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],rs3);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);
        sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],rs2);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);
        sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],rs1);
        //printf("%s\n",sentence);

    }
```

the functions are:

```c
char encrypt(char c, char r[]){

int num=(int)c-65;
char newc;

newc=r[num];

return newc;
}

char relfect(char c){

char reflector[27]={'A','Q','W','S','E','D','R','F','T','G','Y','H','U','J','O','K','I','L','P','Z','V','C','X','B','N','M'};
int num=(int)c-65;
char newc;

newc=reflector[num];

return newc;
}
```

When I compile and execute my code I manage to encrypt the word i input, but when I reset the program and insert the encrypted word it doesnt decrypt it, which seems odd.

EXAMPLE:
If I input Hello I get QOBAJ but in I restart the program and enter QOBAJ I get MWCJC instead of Hello and i can't figure out why.

The rotors i use are:

1-  EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ

2-  AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE

3-  BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO

Thank you for helping me.

Lorenzo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I don't see where you initialize the variables `j` or `z` and you never use the variable `q` after assigning a value to it. Assuming that you do initialize everything, that you don't need the variable `q` and that your code is otherwise correct then the problem is here:

```
if (z==26){
    z=0;
    temp=rs2[0];
    for(int s=0;s<26-1;s++)
    {
        rs2[s]=rs2[s+1];
    }
    rs2[26-1]=temp;
}
```

In this block of code you should be working with `rs3` not `rs2`. It looks like you did a copy and paste but did not change all of the names.

**EDIT:**

You must reverse the lookup mechanism for decryption and you do not need a `reflect` function. Replace

```
sentence[i]=reflect(sentence[i]);
```

with:

```
sentence[i]=encrypt(sentence[i],reflector);
```

The `decrypt` function will look like this:

```
char decrypt(char c, char r[])
{
    for ( int num = 0; num < 26; ++num )
    {
        if ( r[num] == c )
        {
            return((char)(65 + num));
        }
    }
    return(c); // Should never get here
}
```

Then to perform decryption, call `decrypt` instead of `encrypt`.

Comment: My apologies, I corrected that part, q was used for debugging in a previous version of the code, I forgot to delete it. The variables are all initialized at the beginning of the main. if you want to see more of it i uploaded the code to my [github](https://github.com/Tabamon/Enigma)